# Why does my log in form connect with empty password field?

Tags: java, netbeans, xampp, netbeans-platform

My log in form only requires password in order to log in. When I type incorrect strings, it works but when i type space or leave it, it logs me in. what is the cause of this problem? Im also using xampp mysql as my database.

```
public class loginPage extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  public Connection cn;
  public Statement st;
  public mainPage mainPage;
  public forgotPage forgotPage;

    /**
     * Creates new form loginPage
     */
    public loginPage() {
        initComponents();
    try{ 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/soften?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","");
            st=cn.createStatement();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connected");
    }catch(Exception e){}        

    }


private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   try{
       String sql="select * from tblpassword where password = '"+String.valueOf(editPass.getPassword())+"'";

  ResultSet rss=st.executeQuery(sql);
  if(rss.next()&&sql!=null){
      mainPage = new mainPage();
      mainPage.setVisible(true);
      this.dispose();

  }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Password");}
   }catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Password");}
```

this is my code

Comment: what are the rows in your password table. `&&sql!=null` will always be true. if excepted in assignment it wont even execute.

Comment: Also - read up on sql injection - will be important if you ever use this code in any production sense.

Comment: I was messing with the code and forgot to remove it, anyways thanks for the answer, I will try to disable the login button when the password field is empty, there is only one row in my password table